# Ajax call on selection change not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Dropdown selection change is not firing when the function contain ajax call. if the function contains only an alert, the function works.

Here is the code:

```
 <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Select Category</label>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CategoryId, new SelectList(Model.Categories, "CategoryId", "CategoryName", Model.CategoryId),
                            new { @class = "form-control select2", id = "myCategories" })

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" id="makes">

                    </div>

                </div>
```

Here is the js function

```
    @section scripts{

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document.body).on('change', "#myCategories", function (event) {
            var selected = $('#myCategories').val();
            alert("catid changed to : " + selected);
            $.ajax({
                url : @Url.Action("getMakes","Transaction", new {categoryId= Model.CategoryId}),
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                    $('#makes').html = data;
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("failed");
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
}
```

If I comment the ajax block, it works and shows the alert. Anyone know why it is behaving like this?

Comment: `begin` is not a default `$.ajax()` option. Does `@Url.Action("getMakes","Transaction", new {categoryId= Model.CategoryId})` return a  string that is a valid URL? What is purpose of setting `type` to `POST` where no data is sent to server?

Comment: i tried GET also, but it is not working and i removed everything other than the success, still it is not working

Comment: Have you tried using a string for value of `url`?

Comment: yes i tried that, I checked the value of url generated in the inspector. it is valid.

Comment: `.html = data` should be `.html(data)`. Can you include rendered `html` at Question?

Comment: But, do you know why it is not showing the alert

Comment: Is `alert("failed");` called? Are there any errors logged at `console`?

Comment: Put 'debugger' before ajax call and check URL string... Is it correct or not..

Comment: @guest271314 No alert is showing

Comment: @sony Even this alert("catid changed to : " + selected); too???

Comment: Is `change` event called? Can you include `html` of `#myCategories` at Question?

Comment: @AnilTalla i don't know how to do that? can you tell how to put the debugger before the call or a simple debug.log is what you mentioned

Comment: @guest271314 nothing is being called and even the alert before the ajax is not showing.`html` of `#myCategories` is there in the question. the first part

Comment: @sony Can you put this as the first line in your fuction: `alert("Called!");`

Comment: @CodingYoshi it shows the changed alert when i remove the ajax part

Comment: @sony In between alert and ajax, like this,  `alert("catid changed to : " + selected); debugger;
            $.ajax({`  then open developer tools, change select option. I tried ajax call which you are added in the code. It is working properly. May be URL is not correct I guess.

Comment: @sony So with the ajax, that exact line I gave you does not show an alert. The exact line without any variables.

Comment: @AnilTalla What does it have to do with the URL? the alert is before the url comes into play

Comment: @AnilTalla let me check it

Comment: @sony Is there any error in the `console` tab

Comment: @AnilTalla nothing happend

Comment: @AnilTalla it is showing an invalid regular expression on the url line when the page is loaded

Comment: @sony Because of that it is not calling. **Test. 1**: Remove that @URL line and write url directly. `url: "www.google.com"` like this , it should work. **Test 2**: Remove ajax call and write `console.log( @Url.Action("getMakes","Transaction", new {categoryId= Model.CategoryId})')` check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all those who helped me to fix this problem even though it is Christmas. Finally i got it working by putting  single inverted comma before and after the url part in the ajax. Thanks @AnilTalla for the console clue. Here is the updated js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(document.body).on('change', "#myCategories", function (event) {
            var selected = $('#myCategories').val();
            alert("catid changed to : " + selected);
            $.ajax({
                url : '@Url.Action("getMakes","Transaction", new {categoryId= Model.CategoryId})',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                    $('#makes').html = data;
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("failed");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

**Merry Christmas everyone.**

Comment: No you should put the answer here and leave your question as it was

Comment: Thank you, wish you the same @sony